# Granular Control of Intel Speedstep? - Skylake Windows 10

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, power-options, speedstep

Currently both "Balanced" and "Power saver" power plans claim the minimum processor state is 5%, maximum is 100% and the cooling policy is passive.

However on power saver the processor (i7 6700HQ) will rarely climb above 900MHz and I've never seen it go above 1.1Ghz, keeping the fans very quiet.
Balanced on the other hand will take the processor all the way up to 3GHz, causing the fans to spin up quite a bit, clearly something else is going on here.

I would like the ability to have some middle ground that performs better than power saver but wont go as high as balanced, but according to windows the plans are identical in terms of the processor. Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a tool called [ThrottleStop](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/) that'll let you do this and it'll give you a lot more control over your CPU.

Here are a couple of options:

1. Disabling turbo - this can be done by just ticking the box
2. Changing the speed shift settings - it's on a scale from 0 to 255 with 0 giving you the highest clock speed and 255 giving you the lowest. I've found that when using 128, it'll idle at ~1GHz, but will boost to full if a heavy load is put on on the CPU. You can do this by going to TPL, and making sure that the *Enable Speed Shift when ThrottleStop starts* box is ticked, and then editing the Speed Shift value

[Here's](https://www.notebookcheck.net/How-to-Lower-Temperatures-Stop-Throttling-and-Increase-Battery-Life-The-ThrottleStop-Guide-2017.213140.0.html) a good guide on how to use ThrottleStop - you might find some solutions there that work better for you. Note that after you've applied the settings, you'll want to make an entry in Task Scheduler to make it launch every time your computer boots.

Finally, if you're having trouble with overheating, you might want to try to undervolt your CPU (i7 6700HQs can undervolt quite far), as it can reduce the temps by a few degrees (the link mentioned above has a good guide on that too). Just be aware that it **will** void your warranty if you undervolt.